# UK Spouse Visa Accommodation requirement

Tags: united-kingdom, dependent-visa

I would like to use this opportunity to thank the moderators and contributors of this forum. You guys are doing a wonderful job.

I have a question regarding accommodation requirement for UK Spouse Visa. All the other requirements have been met.

I'm the applicant. I live abroad. My wife has ILR and daughter has British citizenship and they are both resident in the UK. They presently live in a 2 bedroom and 1 living room apartment with my Father-in-law. We are scared of a refusal. So we want to rent a 2bedroom apartment.

Here is the problem: Is it acceptable to use this newly rented apartment to meet the accommodation requirement by providing only Tenancy agreement and letter from landlord with permission for me to live in the apartment? It is a newly rented apartment. So no utility bills. And we don't want to wait until we have utility bills for the apartment. Also, is a property inspection necessary for this apartment, given that it would be occupied by only my wife and daughter?

Thank you.

Comment: How old is you daughter? A separate bedroom for a 6 mo is unlikely needed, but for an 18 yo would be. I think the size (square meters of the flat also matters).

Comment: @StrongBad: She is 14months old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a child that age (14 months old at the time of posting), a two bedroom apartment is just fine. As long as you describe your situation in a letter, along with your rental agreement, that should suffice. Here is the [most recent accommodation requirement](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/maintenance-and-accommodation-maa/maintenance-and-accommodation-maa--2#maa9-assessing-adequate-accommodation).

Comment: Yes, we ended up using the two bedroom apartment( it has one living room and one bedroom) and i was granted the visa. It seems like a long time ago now. Funny how time flies.

Comment: That's really cool! If the answer is useful and answers the question satisfactorily, would you mind choosing it as an answer? It helps our percentages and such.